# Accessing constants in Angular UI router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a constants file.

```
var app = angular.module('ops.services');

app.constant('opsConstants', {
    GID: 'UA1'
});

app.service('OpsConstantService', OpsConstantService);

OpsConstantService.$inject = ['opsConstants'];

function OpsConstantService(opsConstants){
    this.OPSCONSTANTS = opsConstants;

}
```

`My app module` depends on the same, and **DI** has been provided.

```
var opsApp = angular.module('opsApp', ['ui.router',  'ops.services', 'angular-momentjs']);
```

And,now, In my app, `routing` I need to access the constants value.

```
opsApp.config(routerConfig);

routerConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];

function routerConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home/dashboard/");

    $stateProvider
        .state('Modal', {
            url: '^/modal/{obj_id}/{name}/{tab_id}/{start_date}/{end_date}/{repos}',
            resolve: {
                ModalTabs: ['OpsConstantService',function(OpsConstantService){
                    return OpsConstantService.opsConstants.GID;
                }]

            },
            views: {
                'repo@': {
                    templateUrl: function(stateParams) {
                        debugger; // I am not able to get the GID value here
                        var tab_id = stateParams.tab_id;
                        return 'src/modals/nodes/' + tab_id + '/' + 'my_bp.html';
                    }
                },
```

I am trying to `resolve` but alas! nothing works.

**How to access the constants value so that I can dynamically configure which template to render?**

**UPDATE**

If I do,

```
routerConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider','OpsConstantService'];

function routerConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,OpsConstantService) {
```

I get `injector module` error.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem are the different angular bootstrapping phases. Short explanation:

The state declaration is inside the .config phase of angular. In this phase angular.service's are not available (side note: in angular.run phase they are available).

If you need this, you need to build your service as angular.provider instead, they are accessable in this phase. Also your constants themselves should also available.

Comment: I can't access the constants here right? Can you tell me how to access the same.

Comment: @StrugglingCoder you can access the constants with opsConstants injection instead of OpsConstantService